# save JSON data to rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've created a autocomplete searchfield in which users can type a movie title and it will show all the results like this > https://i.stack.imgur.com/xifLk.png

The next thing I want to do is give the user a option to save a movie title to the database. As you can see in the image every result has a "add" button. This is a link with the ID of the movie in it's target. It can be anything like a button or a span etc.

When a user clicks on the add button I want to store the movie title of the movie with that ID in my database.

I've generated a model called movie and a collumn called title. I've also generated a controller called movie and I've created a form field which lets the user type the movie title and then save it to do movie model > title collumn. But this was more for testing. Like I said above I want to save the movie title from a specific ID into my database.

I know how to get the JSON respons from TMDB api, 
[click](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/62?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4)

But what I don't know is how to link my "add" button to that response and then grab some data like title or poster url and post it in my database.

Comment: Do you want to save the `results` key data of the returned JSON?

Comment: After some thinking I've come up with an idear. I'll add the ID over every movie to a href, when that's clicked I'll do a request for the data of that ID and store that in my DB.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to save the `results` key from the JSON returned. You can do something like below

```
require 'rest-client'

#Assuming you have a responses table or any other where you want to save
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base

  def save_results
    data = RestClient.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=i+know+what+you')
    parsed_json =  JSON.parse(data)
    #If you have a result column, you may save it there
    self.results = parsed_json['results']
    save!
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to save the `original_title` in my `title` collumn in my `movie` model. So your code would go into my models folder `movie.rb`.

But I only want to save the `original_title` of the selected movie. So how would I get that data?

Comment: The `.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=i+know+what+you')` should be ID of the selected movie like this 
`.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/62?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4')` but how would I get that data from the view into the model?